# phpword work with addlink within msword

Tags: php, phpword

It is possible add link within msword document on PHPWORD? I want to **add link each sheet of msword document**. And **this link forwarded to top of the document** (1-page document). If it is possible, can we will write examples?

Answer (score 1):

PhpWord samples are a good starting place to look for things: there is a simple example available at [phpword github samples](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_35_InternalLink.php) that shows how this is done.

A simplified example how to use the internal links:

```
// adding an internal bookmark
$section->addBookmark('MyBookmark');

// adding a link to the internal bookmark
$section->addLink('MyBookmark', htmlspecialchars('Take me to the first page', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), null, null, true);
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer very usefull:)